# java swing : display file system in jtree, and how to open the file

Tags: java, swing

I am using jsplit pane, in left component , there is tree view that display folder and file of home directory. When i click on the leaf node of a tree , if it is not a directory, then file (image, pdf, text, video, etc..) should open in right component of jsplit pane.

how can i display that file right component of jsplit pane when we select file in jtree in left pane.

Please provide code snippets Its urgent.
Thanks

Comment: "how can i display that file right component of jsplit pane when we select file in jtree in left pane."  That question amounts to 'how do I load every document type ever created (including the ones not yet thought up)?'.  Oh, and if you have a question, no matter how far reaching, please don't forget to add a question mark.

Comment: You want to display the content of the file or a icon representing the file, like in Windows Explorer?

Comment: See also http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/treeselectionlistener.html

Answer (score 1):

Like this?
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/DisplayafilesysteminaJTreeview.htm

Comment: yes link you have display the file system in jtree. In my applicaton i have left component to display the jtree.

Comment: When we select the file (a non leaf node) from jtree , the file( of any type i.e txt, pdf ,jpeg etc.) should open in right component of jsplitpane.

Comment: There is no one common code for al kinds of files you may have. You should add a listener to the tree. If file is selected your code should check the file format and open proper component to display the file e.g. JTextArea for .txt files or JLabel with ImageIcon for .jpeg or .gif etc.

Answer (score 1):

This not possible. There is no way to be able "display" the file on the right side.  You can however display some information about the file and/or define certain formats that you will be able to display (images, text, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

First, create the JTree. For the next step, you need to override the `valueChanged` method as shown below. Note that your class needs to implement `TreeSelectionListener` to look for the `TreeSelectionEvent`.

```
//tree selction event on the tree triggers this method
public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
        //which node was selected
        DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)tree.getLastSelectedPathComponent();
        if (node == null) return;
        Object nodeInfo = node.getUserObject();

        //if node is a leaf
        if (node.isLeaf()) {
        //do something with the above object
```

Perhaps you can run a `toString` on the `nodeInfo` object and use this string to retrieve details about that file from the database and respectively display its details on the right side of the JSplitPane.